# What does semi-transparent CSS properties mean in Google Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Please see the following picture:

[image]

Why is `padding-top` and `margin-top` fully opaque, but `padding-right` etc. not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe they are semi-transparent because they're not explicitly defined.

Consired following sheet:

```
selector1 {
    margin: 20px;
}

selector2 {
    margin: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

selector3 {
    margin: 10px 20px 30px;
}
```

In first example (`selector1`) all `margin-*` properties will be semi-transparent because non is explicitly defined - shortcut is being used.

In second example (`selector2`) only `margin-top` will be fully opaque, as it's defined in its own property.

In last example (`selector3`), `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` are defined explicitly, therefore the will be fully opaque. However `margin-left` and `margin-right` are defined by a single value, so they will be semi-transparent.

---

Semi-transparent color is also applied to default values, for instance:

```
background: red url(...) no-repeat;
```

This property defined `background-color`, `background-image` and `background-repeat` explicitly, however `background-position`, `background-clip`, `background-size` etc. are not defined (default values are used) so they will be seen as semi-transparent.

Comment: Actually, I'm explicitly defining `padding: 20px` and `margin: -20px`. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Grey colored entries are rules that are not defined but instead computed at runtime. Please refer [this page](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/edit-styles)